# ICACLS Setowner to folders only

Tags: windows, ownership, icacls

I need to give `user_foo` full control in all files and subdirectories in a \directory.

`user_foo` is the owner of the /directory.
`user_foo` has own some subdirectories but not all subdirectories.

`icacls \directory /grant user_foo:(OI)(CI)F /T /C`

I believe, (please, confirm me), I have to get ownership of all subdirectories first.

`icacls \directory /setowner user_foo /t /c`

However, I don't want to get ownership of files. Folders must enough. /t parameter affects all the files under \directory.

Any help is appreciated.

PS. All existing permissions should remain.

Comment: Please move your question to superuser. Stack Overflow is about programming https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A user doesn't have to own a directory to be granted full control of it.

Comment: @montonero Sorry. I didn't know that. I'll ask it at superuser. Thanks.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, they don't need to be granted but if you want to grant some user you need to have full control. In my case I don't have full control under subdirectories and I don't own the subdirectories but I own the root directory and I need to get full control in subdirectories. How can I do that?

Comment: The user that's running icacls.exe needs the right to modify the discretionary security for files and directories (not necessarily full control, which allows changing the owner). The right to modify file security is implicitly granted to the owner (unless an owner-rights entry overrides it), but changing the owner via `/setowner` requires the right to modify the owner.

Comment: An administrator can use SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege via takeown.exe to set the Administrators group as the owner and thus implicitly get access to modify the security.

Comment: Working around an owner-rights entry that doesn't grant the right to modify file security may require forced access via SeRestorePrivilege and opening files and directories with the backup-semantics flag. The GUI ACL editor can handle this owner-rights case, but icacls.exe cannot.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for all the comments but I can not say that I get it completely. I'll ask one simple question. Please answer as simple as you can since I am a newb.

There is a directory that I own and I have full control.
I need to give full control to some other user for some folders in that main directory.
However I don't have full control or ownership in those subdirectories. What should I do?

Comment: It's specifically about `WDAC` access, which you can have even if you're not the owner, but you may not have it even on the files and directories in your "full control" directory, since inheritance can be disabled. I doubt you have `WO` (write owner) access if you don't have `WDAC` access, in which case `/setowner` will fail. Then you'll need to use SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege (as an administrator) via takeown.exe to set the owner to your current user or the administrators group. It is not sufficient to just take ownership of directories; you must own a file to *implicitly* get `WDAC` access.

Comment: You want a fine level of control over this, which you're not going to get with a single command unless there were a "try to take ownership if this fails" command. You could use a nested `for` loop in CMD with an outer `/r` loop to walk the directory tree, and an inner loop that individually tries to modify the security of the directory and each file in it via icacls.exe. If the icacls.exe command fails, try to take ownership via takeown.exe and retry the command.